# How can I Convert Html to a String without stripping formatting settings?

Tags: java, android, html, string-formatting

I am trying to take a text document, split it, and search for results. If results match then the text will be replaced with equivalent text, just formatted (Bold, underlined, etc.). Here is my code:

```
String[] result = conversionText.split("//n");

for (int a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {


        result[a] = result[a].replaceAll("important", " \n" + Html.fromHtml("<u>IMPORTANT</u>"));

        verifyTextView.setText(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
```

I have tried grabbing a string resource, but with the same formatting shown above, however the problem persisted. How can I keep the formatting on the text when placing it into a string?

Comment: Please remove the "javascript" tag, since this question concerns Java, not Javascript.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Nope that doesn't make a difference. But I find it interesting that when I remove the " \n"  it throws an error saying I am trying to put Spanned text inside a string. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: did you tried `Html.fromHtml()` while setting the `TextView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
Just read the `TextView#setText(CharSequence text)` reference. Which states:

> Sets the string value of the TextView. **TextView does not accept HTML-like formatting**, which you can do with text strings in XML resource files.

Which explains why you can't just do something like...

```
verifyTextView.setText("<p>Hello, world!</p>");
```

However the following code should work:

```
String[] result = conversionText.split("//n");

for (int a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
    result[a] = result[a].replaceAll("important", " <br><u>IMPORTANT</u>");
}

verifyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(Arrays.toString(result)));
```